# Why does ^#.*#$ not capture recursively inserted files?

Tags: dired, regular-expressions

While considering some refactoring, I made changes throughout a project.

Halfway through the changes, and before saving, I found it doesn't quite work. I exited emacs and restarted. (That's probably not the right approach. There must be some kind of "ignore-all-changes-done-so-far" command I'm missing.)

Regardless, I now have many `filename.ext` that are left with a trail of `#filename.ext#`.

I recursively insert directories in dired-mode starting from the project root, and flag (%-d) all files of the regexp `^#.*#$` for deletion.

This expression only captures the files at the root of the hierarchy. Why, and how can I modify it to also catch all files inside the hierarchy?

**Comparison**

By way of comparison, marking (or flagging) all files of the pattern `^.*\.js$` does indeed catch all files, in both the root and in recursive directories. So why is `^#.*#$` not good?

Comment: There is a function `diredp-mark-files-regexp-recursive` in the package `dired+`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are asking how to flag all files whose names look
like auto-save files—that is, files whose names begin and end with **`#`**.

In Dired (including vanilla Dired and Dired+), the key **`#`** does exactly that.

`C-h k #` says:

> **`#`** runs the command `dired-flag-auto-save-files`, which is an interactive
>     compiled Lisp function in `dired.el`.
>
> It is bound to `#`, `menu-bar mark mark-flag marks-flag-auto-save-files`.
>
> `(dired-flag-auto-save-files &optional UNFLAG-P)`
>
> Flag for deletion files whose names suggest they are auto save files.
>
> A prefix argument says to unmark or unflag those files instead.

See also the Emacs manual, node [Flagging Many Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Flagging-Many-Files.html).

You can also find this command as menu-item **Flag Auto-save Files** in menu-bar menu **Mark**.  (In [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) this menu item is in menu **Marks**, submenu **Flag**.)

---

As for the question why regexp `^#.*#$` does not work (used with `%d` or `%m`, for example) in inserted subdirectories: It's because for subdirectories the full file name is picked up, i.e., including the directory part.

You can use regexp `^.*/?#.*#$` to do what you want for all `#...#` files in the current Dired buffer, i.e., including all inserted subdirs.

Comment: That does solve the problem, though understanding the reason why the regex is incorrect would also be nice. I guess hunting in the code for what pressing '#' in Dired does will reveal the correct regexp, and then it will be a matter of understanding why the two do not capture the same set.

Comment: I've updated the answer to address this.